# Passing main component state to another component error

Tags: reactjs

What I want to do is take the list that is in the main component state and pass it to the List component as a prop.

It is not working and I get the  'state' is not defined error. Don't know why.
This is my code.

```
import React from 'react';
import List from './components/List';

import './App.css';

function App() {

  state = {
   list: [
     {
       id: 1,
       place: 'Doesn't matter',
       reserved: false
     },

   ]
 } 
 return (
   <div className="App">
    <List  list={this.state.list} />
   </div>
 );
}

export default App;
```

list component List.js

```
import React from 'react';



function App() {
 return (
   <div className="App">
    <h1>app</h1>
   </div>
 );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: you cannot use `this` in a functional component

Comment: and functional components don't have a state.

Comment: Of couse a functional component have a state since React 16.8, with the state hook

Comment: yes, if we use hooks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may follow this approach too, I mean you can convert your App function to a component class where you can use state

App.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import List from "./list";

class App extends Component {
  state = {
    list: [
      {
        id: 1,
        place: "Doesn't matter",
        reserved: false
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        place: "Matter",
        reserved: true
      }
    ]
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className={"App"}>
        <List list={this.state.list}></List>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

And then make your list as functional component where you just want to play with props

list component

```
import React from "react";
const List = ({ list }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <ul>
        {list.map(l => (
          <li key={l.id}>{l.place}</li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
};

export default List;
```

Hope it will help you

Answer (score 1):

In a functional component you need to use useState() function instead of state property

```
function App() {

const [list, setList] = useState([
     {
       id: 1,
       place: 'Doesn't matter',
       reserved: false
     },

   ]);

 return (
   <div className="App">
    <List list={list} />
   </div>
 );
}
```

More info on https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html

Answer (score 0):

Here is the sample working example using hooks and state [codesandebox](https://codesandbox.io/s/hooks-and-state-f25fd)